# Custom format to strikethrough text in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to use an excel to track changes. In a cell is the old and the new value, separated with a linebreak.
For readability, I strike through the old value and then manually change the font color to red. So in one cell I have in red and strikethrough the old value and below (same cell) the new value.

I am looking for a way to make the formatting easier. Ideally, when I strikethrough some text within a cell, the text automaticly changes to a red font without changing the rest of the cell.

I tried conditional formatting with a VBA Module. But that worked only for the whole cell and not text within a cell.

```
Function StrikeThru(rng As Range)
   StrikeThru = rng.Font.Strikethrough
End Function
```

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/conditional-formatting-if-the-cell-contains-a/b5ab42d3-b2cc-46b0-8e95-202bf4bd356f)

Is there a way to achieve this only for the marked text within a cell?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `characters`-property of the `range`-object

```
Public Sub strikeThroughFirstParagraph(c As Range)

Dim posLinebreak
posLinebreak = InStr(c.Text, vbLf)

If posLinebreak > 0 Then
    With c.Characters(1, posLinebreak - 1).Font
        .strikeThrough = True
        .Color = vbRed
    End With
End If

End Sub
```